# gmodule-2.0 not found while compiling

Tags: gnome, gtk, cmake, gtk3, glib

I can't figure it out. I seem to have all deps installed, but I'm getting the following error while trying to compile ValaPanel on Xenial:

```
./configure
```

Will output:

```
-- Looking for RPMTools... - rpmbuild NOT FOUND
-- checking for a minimum Vala version of 0.34
--   found Vala, version 0.36.7
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0>=3.22'
--   
-- Checking for module 'glib-2.0>=2.50'
--   
-- Checking for module 'gio-2.0>=2.50'
--   
-- Checking for module 'gio-unix-2.0>=2.50'
--   
-- Checking for module 'gthread-2.0>=2.50'
--   
-- Checking for module 'gmodule-2.0>=2.50'
--   
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:367 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:532 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:130 (pkg_check_modules)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `libglib2.0-dev` package is probably outdated. It provides file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gmodule-2.0.pc` where version is `2.48.2` and does not satisfy requirement for `vala-panel` build. I would suggest to update `libglib2.0-dev` by backporting package from newer version or manually.

Comment: But.. I'm on Xenial.